# How to fetch div value with specific id using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child, parent-selector

I have list of data with add button . On button click how to get value of div with id="rnumber" with jquery .i want number on button click. i don't know how to get that number i try  but every time i get first number of list  i want number of same class . ex. if i click on second li button still i get first li class div value .
I try with parents and child selector but i don't get anwser.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <ul class="searchresult" style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li>
            <div  class="kt-font-lg">AKash</div>
            <div  class="kt-font-lg rnumber" >1234567890</div>
            <button  class="kt-font-lg btn-primary " onclick="addNumber()">Add</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div  class="kt-font-lg">Deep</div>
            <div  class="kt-font-lg rnumber" >9012345678</div>
            <button  class="kt-font-lg btn-primary " onclick="addNumber()">Add</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**onClick function** :

```
function addNumber(){
                rnumber = $('#rnumber');
                var  ttt = rnumber.text();
                console.log(ttt);        
             }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for click event

Comment: You mean to say, you can use something like this, right? `$("#rnumber")`?

Comment: your HTML is invalid, you have 2 `<div>`s with the same `id` attribute.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar i update my quetions , please check again

Comment: @Meet I have answered and solved your question. Kindly check my answer.

Comment: @Meet: Praveen has posted the correct answer below. Have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have to keep your IDs unique. Duplicating IDs is a crime.** Change it to a `class` instead. Since multiple elements share the same function, use `event.target` or `this`. You can use something like this:

```js
function addNumber() {
  console.log($(event.target).prev().text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <ul class="searchresult" style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li>
      <div class="kt-font-lg">AKash</div>
      <div class="kt-font-lg rnumber">1234567890</div>
      <button class="kt-font-lg btn-primary" onclick="addNumber()">Add</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="kt-font-lg">Deep</div>
      <div class="kt-font-lg rnumber">9012345678</div>
      <button class="kt-font-lg btn-primary" onclick="addNumber()">Add</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In a better way, use unobtrusive JavaScript event handling:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".btn-primary").click(function () {
    console.log($(this).prev().text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <ul class="searchresult" style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li>
      <div class="kt-font-lg">AKash</div>
      <div class="kt-font-lg rnumber">1234567890</div>
      <button class="kt-font-lg btn-primary">Add</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="kt-font-lg">Deep</div>
      <div class="kt-font-lg rnumber">9012345678</div>
      <button class="kt-font-lg btn-primary">Add</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have **invalid HTML** by using same  `Id` attribute value on two `<div>`s I changed it to class attribute, here is a working snippet using `.prev()` method and also note how I passed the element to the event handler:

```js
function addNumber(el){
  const text = $(el).prev().text();
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
    <ul class="searchresult" style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li>
            <div  class="kt-font-lg">AKash</div>
            <div  class="kt-font-lg " class="rnumber">1234567890</div>
            <button  class="kt-font-lg btn-primary " onclick="addNumber(this)">Add</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div  class="kt-font-lg">Deep</div>
            <div  class="kt-font-lg " class="rnumber">9012345678</div>
            <button  class="kt-font-lg btn-primary " onclick="addNumber(this)">Add</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".click-number").click(function(){
  var rnumber = $(this).data('rnumber');
  console.log(rnumber);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
    <ul class="searchresult" style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li>
            <div  class="kt-font-lg">AKash</div>
            <div  class="kt-font-lg ">1234567890</div>
 <button  class="kt-font-lg btn-primary click-number" data-rnumber="1234567890">Add</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div  class="kt-font-lg">Deep</div>
            <div  class="kt-font-lg ">9012345678</div>
 <button  class="kt-font-lg btn-primary click-number" data-rnumber="9012345678">Add</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You cannot set the same id with two div elements
class click-number is the easy way. Put the number as data-rnumber and get it in jquery.